# Switch to XMLSerializer in inner classes

Tags: c#, wcf

From [this guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class#manually-switching-to-the-xmlserializer), one may set the service interface to be serialized with `DataContract`, and then all rest of referenced classes from the methods's API would inherit such serializer as well, unless overriding specific classes with e.g. `[XMLSerializerFormat]`.

But, is it possible to do the opposite? That is, keeping the main service interface with the `XMLSerializer` default serializer, and override few classes to use `DataContractFormat`. Per my sample application (and testing), doing so does not seem to switch to the `DataContract` (doesn't syncronize the attributes to the client's service reference).

It's for an attribute like this:

```
//[XmlIgnore]
[DataMember]
public string Var
{
    get => _var;
    set => _var= value;
}
```